# AsEnumerable doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm building a shopping cart project for our school project, I found a great tutorial, but I'm stuck at adding products to my shopping cart.

What I want is that when a user who has already added a product, it cannot be added anymore.

I think it is the part when checking `ProductID` in datatable in session
and this is my code:

```
protected void btnaddtocart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   string ProductID = Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString();
   string ProductQuantity = "1";

   DataListItem currentItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;
   Label lblavailablestock = currentItem.FindControl("lblavailablestock") as Label;

   if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
   {
       DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
       var checkproduct = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID); 

        // I think this line above is the error because it always proceeds on adding the product.
       if (checkproduct.Count() == 0)
       {
           string query = "select * from Products where ProductID =  " + ProductID;
           DataTable dtproducts = GetData(query);

           DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
           dr["ProductID"] = LinkButton2.Text;
           dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
           dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
           dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
           dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
           dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
           dr["AvailableStock"] = lblavailablestock.Text;

           dt.Rows.Add(dr);

           Session["MyCart"] = dt;
           lblitems.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
       }          
   }       
   else
   {
       string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID;
       DataTable dtproducts = GetData(query);

       DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("ProductQuantity", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("AvailableStock", typeof(string));

       DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
       dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
       dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
       dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
       dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
       dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtproducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
       dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
       dr["AvailableStock"] = lblavailablestock.Text;

       dt.Rows.Add(dr);

       Session["MyCart"] = dt;
   }

   highlightproduct();
}
```

Thank you so much for everyone who will help me! :)

Comment: worst case if you can't get linq to work would be to use the dt.Select() method

Comment: I can assure you that `AsEnumerable` does actually work.  There may or may not be a bug in YOUR code, but since you haven't said what the problem is, no one can really tell.  Try harder next time, we expect high quality questions.

Comment: im getting a null value at checkproduct

Comment: the problem is when i already added a certain product it shouldnt be added anymore but it is still being added

Comment: Use a debugger and examine `dt` at that point. There are *so many ways* for your code to fail it's not really feasible for us to help you out without any information.

Comment: It makes no sense to me that, when you look for an existing product, you are using `ProductID`, which is initialised using `Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString()`, yet when you add a product you use `LinkButton2.Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ProductID you're checking for in the cart is not the same value that you add to the cart.  One is the command argument and the other is the button text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rows from datatable to query

```
var checkproduct = dt.Rows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID);
```